# Delete host from dns zone

Tags: c#, dns, wmi

I am trying to delete host using below code from selected zone but not deleting.

```
     string Query = "SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_Zone WHERE ContainerName = '" + ZoneName    + "' and OwnerName='" + recordName + "'";

      ObjectQuery qry = new ObjectQuery(Query);
      ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + dnsServerName + "\\root\\MicrosoftDNS");
      scope.Connect();
      ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, qry);
            ManagementObjectCollection col = s.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in col)
            {
                obj.Delete();
            }
```

Please help.

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injection!

Comment: If it were SQL, and not the WMI dialect.

Comment: @rahul: i want to delete record from selected zone in dns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is code for delete the domain record.

```
 bool DeleteRecordFromDns(string ZoneName, string dnsServerName, string recordName)
    {
        try
        {
            string Query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_AType WHERE OwnerName = '{0}.{1}'", recordName, ZoneName);
            ObjectQuery qry = new ObjectQuery(Query);
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + dnsServerName + "\\root\\MicrosoftDNS");
            scope.Connect();
            ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, qry);
            ManagementObjectCollection col = s.Get();
            if (col.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in col)
                {
                    obj.Delete();
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```